# Why does casting different pointer types cause TBAA (Type-Based Alias Analysis) violation?

Tags: c, casting, strict-aliasing

I was reading this [blog](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html), and then I found some code that
I don't really understand.  Why is this bad code?

```
float *P;

void zero_array() {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
  P[i] = 0.0f;
}

int main() {
  P = (float*)&P;  // cast causes TBAA violation in zero_array.
  zero_array();
}
```

I hope someone could explain it please.

Comment: So, P points to itself.  Sound OK to me.

Comment: @MartinJames UB, violates aliasing rules

Comment: Ahh... it's a float pointer that is pointing to a float* instead of a float... right!

Comment: are you asking *Why does C have this rule?*, or *How does this code violate the rules of C?*

Comment: @M.M: How this code violate the this rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code:

```
float *P;
P = (float*)&P; 
P[0] = 0.0f;
```

violates the strict aliasing rule.

The object `P` has *effective type* `float *`, because that is its declared type. C11 6.5/6:

> The effective type of an object for an access to its stored value is the declared type of the object, if any.

After the second line has executed, the expression `P[0]` denotes the same memory location as `P`.  (Note: imagine `sizeof(float) == sizeof(float *)` for purposes of this explanation. Clearly, if those sizes are different then the situation is even worse!)

Executing `P[0] = 0.0f` uses an lvalue of type `float` to access an object of type `float *`. This violates 6.5/7:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types

In these quotes, "access" means *read or write*. The list of "following types" does not include any exception that covers using a `float` expression to read a `float *`

---

This example is a little difficult to get your head around , because it is self-referential. However it is exactly the same principle as this simpler example:

```
float *Q;
float *P = &Q;
*P = 0.0f;
```

In this case `Q` has type `float *`, but it is written via an lvalue of type `float`.

---

This example demonstrates the rationale for the rule. Suppose the strict aliasing rule did not exist, and all aliasing were permitted.  Then the evaluation `P[0] = 0.0f` changes `P`.  On a common implementation this would cause `P` to now be a null pointer, but we could easily imagine some other value being assigned which leaves `P` as a valid pointer to some other variable.

In that case, the line `P[1] = 0.0f` *must* write the other variable successfully. Therefore, the compiler would not be able to replace the loop with a `memset`; such a memset would update the original location of `P[1]`, but not the new location of `P[1]` after `P[0] = ....;` had been executed.  Optimizations are not allowed to change the observable behaviour of the program.

The existence of the strict aliasing rule means that a compiler can perform optimizations such as changing this loop to a memset, without worrying that the contents of the loop might change the pointer on the fly.

---

NB. The line `P = (float *)&P` may also be an alignment violation. The alignment rule and the strict aliasing rule are completely separate rules and should not be confused with each other.  (Some badly-written pages try to 'explain' strict aliasing as some flavour of alignment requirement).

Comment: What I understand from this code: `float *Q;` `float *P = &Q;` `*P = 0.0f;` is that P points now to the location where Q resides and makes Q point to 0.0f or NULL. am I wrong ?

Comment: @MichaelHeidelberg no, it causes undefined behaviour by violating the strict aliasing rule.  If there were no strict aliasing rule, and your system were IEEE754, and your system used all-bits-zero for null pointers, and `float *` and `float` were the same size in bits, then it would make `Q` be a null pointer.

Comment: Thank you, I got it. also: "and your system used all-bits-zero for null pointers", are there some systems that use different representation for NULL ? ( and that's maybe the reason why we have the NULL constant ) ?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the blog, this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    P[i] = 0.0f;
}
```

Can be optimized to this:

```
memset(P, 0, 40000);
```

This is because `P` is supposed to point to an array of `float`, where a float is 4 bytes (in this example).

But if you do this:

```
P = (float*)&P;
```

Then `P` actually points to an array of *pointers* to `float`.  If a `float *` is 8 bytes in size, the optimization will fail.

Here's a more concrete example:

```
int main() {
    int i;

    P = malloc(10000 * sizeof(float));
    zero_array();   // this properly sets an array of 10000 floats to 0.
    free(P);

    float **PP = malloc(10000 * sizeof(float *));
    P = (float *)PP;
    zero_array();    // if sizeof(float *) == 8, the first 5000 pointers will be NULL, 
                     // and the next 5000 will contain garbage.
    free(PP);
}
```

Comment: Well, technically this is implementation-defined because C doesn't require the usage of IEEE 754, which uses all bits zero to indicate `0.0f`, so there might be another standard representing zero as all bits one, for example. Right?

Comment: @cad technically it is UB (aliasing rules violation), but also note that the C Committee said (in Rationale C99 document): *"As far as the committee knows, all machines treat all bits zero as a  representation of floating-point zero"*

Comment: Why someone would do that ? I mean why would I choose the second alternative to initialize the array to zero ?

Comment: @ouah Oh, wow, never knew of that. Thanks for letting me know that!

Comment: This explanation is bunk . The problem with `P = (float *)&P` is nothing to do with the size of a memset.

Comment: @M.M: the explanation seems fine to me, may be because of my weak knowledge. Could You explain what's going on please?

Comment: "Then `P` actually points to an array of pointers to float" - er, no, it points to a single `float *`.  `P` isn't an array. The "more concrete example" is substantially different; in fact that code is completely legal . Yes it doesn't initialize the space properly, but there's no law against that, you just didn't use the right lengths.